# What tense should I use when speaking about somebody's death?

Tags: tense

In Italian, to say when I was born, I would use the present tense followed by the past participle.

> Sono nato il 18 marzo 1970. (*I was born on 3/18/1970.*)

The reasoning behind that is that I am talking about a fact that is still relevant nowadays (i.e., I am still alive).

The same would be true if I say about somebody's death: For example, talking about J.F. Kennedy, I would say *J.F. Kennedy è morto il 22 novembre 1963*.

In English, what tense should I use when talking about somebody's date of death, the simple past, the present perfect, or the simple present?

Comment: Present simple: https://www.google.it/search?q=george+michael+is+dead&oq=George+Michael+is+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9028j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22george+michael+is+dead%22&tbm=nws and Present Perfect https://www.google.it/search?q=george+michael+is+dead&oq=George+Michael+is+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9028j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22george+michael+has+died%22 another Present Simple https://www.google.it/search?q=george+michael+is+dead&oq=George+Michael+is+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9028j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22george+michael+dies%22

Comment: and Simple Past https://www.google.it/search?q=george+michael+is+dead&oq=George+Michael+is+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9028j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22george+michael+died+in%22

Comment: I can't spare the time to write up a full answer, so anyone is welcome to use those links as best as they see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, you use the simple past for events that occurred completely in the past, including being born or dying.

> I **was born** on May 1st, 1958.
>   He **died** on the 30th of September.

We don't use the perfect for being born or dying, whether or not the person remains alive or dead.  That said, it is *possible* to use the perfect tense, but the rules are the same as for any other verb or condition and aren't special to being born or dying.

Comment: By _the rules_ do you mean also _don't use the perfect tense if it's not strictly necessary_?

Comment: Newspaper headlines will say: "*[CELEBRITY NAME] **is** dead*.." and the present perfect is also common as in: "*[NAME] **has died** in a road accident...*"

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I just mean [the usual ways and standards for using the perfect](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/pastperf.htm).  We generally use the perfect to relate a past event to another event, like *"The doctor came as fast as he could, but Johnson **had already died**."